# UIButton created programmatically. How do I send touch up's to an IBAction?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton which is created programmatically. How do I get this UIButton to send its touch up events to an IBAction I have?

Answer (score 21):

`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method.

```
[myButton addTarget:myClass action:@selector(myEventHandler) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: Selected will receive one parameter: `(id)sender`.

Answer (score 18):

with this line of code you will fire UIbutton action by programmatically

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

For swift

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(functionNameHere), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Only this answers the question

Answer (score 9):

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(myMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Like magic =)

Comment: Normally they use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. The reaction should be on button release, not on depress. And the user should have the option of changing his mind by moving the finger away.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(funcName), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

You can also send the sender to identify the touched button. Plus, don't forget to add objc before your function name:

```
private func setOnClicks() {
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onBtnClick), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func onBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
    print("touched \(sender.tag)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily set add action for `UIButton` using `addTarget(,action:,for:)`

```
let addVehicleButton = UIButton() // Create a button
addVehicleButton.setTitle("Add vehicle", forState: .normal) // set title
addVehicleButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 50, 40) // setting frame
addVehicleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addVehicleButtonClickedAction), for: .touchUpInside) // Add target and control event with trigger function selector
self.view.addSubview(addVehicleButton) // adding to superview
```

**// MARK: - Click action handles**

```
/// Add vehicle button clicked action
    @objc func addVehicleButtonClickedAction() {

    }
```

Comment: thank you, but better add explanations when posting an answer :)